# FluentValidation set validator if condition is true

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation, .net-7.0

I'm trying to get my validator to only validate a complex child property providing that one of the properties in the parent object is true.

In my view model I have:

```
public class PersonDetailsViewModel
{
    public bool? HasDetails { get; set; }
    public BasicDetailsViewModel? BasicDetails { get; set; }
}
```

The `BasicDetailsViewModel` looks like this:

```
public class BasicDetailsViewModel
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? Country { get; set; }
}
```

In my validator for `PersonDetailsViewModel` which is called `PersonDetailsViewModelValidator` I have:

```
public class PersonDetailsViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<PersonDetailsViewModel>
  public PersonDetailsViewModelValidator()
  {
       RuleFor(model => model.BasicDetails)
         .SetValidator(new BasicDetailsViewModelValidator())
         .When(model => model.HasDetails == true);
  }
}
```

In the `BasicDetailsViewModelValidator` :

```
public class BasicDetailsViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BasicDetailsViewModel?>
{
    public BasicDetailsViewModelValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(model => model.FirstName)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(ValidationMessages.Required);

        RuleFor(model => model.Country)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage(ValidationMessages.Required);
    }
}
```

I've put a breakpoint inside the `BasicDetailsViewModelValidator` and some reason whenever `PersonDetailsViewModelValidator` is invoked it hits the breakpoint regardless the value of `HasDetails`.

I expected the breakpoint inside `BasicDetailsViewModelValidator` to only be hit when `HasDetails` is equal to `true`

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or is this expected?

Comment: Are you asking about hitting the breakpoints when `Validate` is called or when the validator is instantiated?

Comment: ^ I think you may be looking at the wrong thing. Write some unit tests (fluent validation has great unit testing support) instead and I would guess they should pass.